# How to install OpenStack with NovaLXD on Ubuntu 16.04+

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

When following these instructions provided by Canonical:

https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#workstation-deployment

I regularly get a failure screen from conjure-up. When I look at the conjure-up.log that it points me to, I see that the neutron-gateway/0 charm has the error "hook failed: 'config-changed'". When I look at the juju logs on the neutron-gateway/0 container, I see the following:

```
DEBUG config-changed ovsvsctl: Error detected while setting up 'eno2':
could not open network device eno2 (No such device).  See ovs-switchd
log for details.
```

My system:

- KVM Virtual Machine
- Ubuntu 16.04.6 Server
- 6 cores
- 24 GB RAM
- 128 GB disk

Comment: This isn't an answer to this specific question, but this is an alternative approach I found that works for the most part: https://linuxhint.com/install_openstack_centos/

Comment: If you're interested in experimenting with OpenStack on a workstation with no installation, [microstack](https://opendev.org/x/microstack) has recently been released.

Comment: Is there a corresponding HA cluster installation of microstack? I'm trying to get a workstation installation working as a way to vet the workflow and tools prior to putting it on hardware.

Comment: Good question. I've filed [a ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/microstack/+bug/1839738) to see if the core devs can provide the correct answer.

Comment: Hi there! microstack does not currently support HA, though it is on the roadmap for the 20.04/20.10 time frame. One caveat: microstack uses kvm rather than lxd under the hood. There's been some discussion of supporting containers, but it's not a roadmap item yet.

Comment: Thanks, @Patch. I'll take a look at microstack sometime in 2020 or 2021, then. In the meantime, I have virtual conjure-up system that might be worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer to this question, but my reason for trying OpenStack w/ NovaLXD was to create a virtual system for testing, and the following will achieve a similar result w/ conjure-up.

I used an amd64 KVM system w/ 8-cores and 32GB RAM.

For the most part, follow the Canonical OpenStack cluster installation instructions here: https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#cluster-deployment

Make the following adjustments:

1) Minimum requirements

- *6* virtual nodes with the following:
- 1 core
- 4 GB RAM (any less starts causing failures) (I haven't completely confirmed that all services function normally with this amount)
- 1 40GB drive (note: the default conjure-up OpenStack configuration prefers two drives per node)
- 2 NICs are required

2) Set up your MAAS hardware

- Create a 'maas' virtual network with DHCP disabled and NAT enabled.
- I used Ubuntu 16.04.

6) Register your hardware with MAAS

- If using KVM, the power configuration type will be `virsh`.
- A `maas` user will need to be configured on the KVM host.
- The `maas` user on the MAAS node will need to be able to SSH via public-key to the KVM host.
- The Power Configuration parameter `Virsh VM ID` will be the VM UUID

11) Configure and deploy the OpenStack services

- If you don't have two drives per node, then you'll need to change a `ceph-osd` parameter, `devices to format and setup as OSD volumes`, to include a local path. I chose `/var/cluster/drive`.